# Android customview performance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, threadpool, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have 2 questions about improving performance:

1. i have a `recyclerview` witch inflates in every row a customview. Every customview has some initialization in his constructor according to model row from `recyclerview`. On first time just an info text will show up and after user click on the row the full customview ( using view.visibility )

   it will make any difference ( good improvements ) if i choose to inflate and make all customview initialization using background threads ? I was thinking of using thread pool with callables and sending holder as parameter
2. in every row above i have an `edittext` witch on click triggers a custom pop-up time picker. At eny time only one row it will be fully visible else only the text info; It will make any difference if the custom pop-up time picker witch is a customview pop-up will be a singleton?

Comment: 1. No ... (inflating should be done on UI thread) 2. No (it will prolly not work as View can have only one parent) ... *Every customview has some initialization in his constructor according to model row from recyclerview* this is not true(or at least it should not) ... as it is RecyclerView ... so Views are reused

Comment: No, if you facing performance issues it is almost always because of loading images. Those need to be scaled down.